Cloudfront signed urls - Incorporating IAM
I am currently working on a little project where I'm serving up an object from an S3 bucket behind cloudfront. I'm studying for certification so I thought it would be useful to have a real world play. Previously, anyone could access the bucket and assosciated object if they had the url that I generate, now I am using the cloudfront signer in a lambda to sign the url that is served up through the front-end. But I want to go further... I want to have it so that only a specific IAM group or assumed role is able to use the link. Say, I have manager staff and restaurant staff - I want the frontend link to be visible to both, but only usable by the manager staff.
I have had a think about cognito pools, or maybe incorpoating some checks on the request user within the lambda, maybe investigating what can be done with paths in cloudfront... but I'm REALLY unsure what the most streamlined approach would be or what is convention and I am struggling to find any examples. So, thank you for any help, even if it's just posting a link to push me in the right direction. Many thanks!

Thinking Get request with Auth header that then utilises a lambda edge function to check auth status of event source user
